# allowLinker out of ga create function

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, shopware

We've got a shop plugin which handles the e-commerce codes for us. However, it is not capable of setting up multidomain.

we can call the require, linker function ourselfes, but the plugin already runs the 'create' function which needs the allowLinker option.

Is it possible to add this after the creation? I've found this resource, which says otherwise - but I am hoping for a hack someone might know.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#allowLinker

Comment: This means you will have no access to the GA code at all? This would prevent most workarounds (like adding the clientID via a set call).  Can you describe what you can do  (i.e. can you add js code before or after the plugin, run server side code etc) ?

Comment: I am able to add JS before and after the analytics code. But I am not able to  alter it. THe snipped is the standard setup: GA create and pageview.

Comment: @Hauke did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Yes, the solution was to extend the plugin. I've created a pull-request but haven't had a look at its status (Keep in mind that question is two years old @FelipeBrahm)